# IBM SQL Next Value for issue

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am trying to write a simple query to get a sequence number.

EXEC SQL SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR @SOP_SEQ INTO :SEQ ;

EXEC SQL SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR @SOP_SEQ INTO :SEQ FROM @SOP_SEQ;

With the first line of code, I get an error message before I can even compile: SQL0104 Token  was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM

I tried the second line of code and I get this error when I compile:
SQL1103 Position 57 Column definitions for table @SOP_SEQ in *LIBL not found.

Can someone point to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the sequence number `FROM` (hint)... Usual SQL syntax includes `Select ... column1, column2 ... FROM tablename`.

Comment: I am opening a web form and want to generate a sequence number only. I am not doing anything else at the moment. Does that mean I have to do a select on a table even though I do not need data?

Comment: The sequence number has to come from somewhere and once you get the next value, where are you going to store it for future values?

Comment: Yes the sequence number comes from Create Sequence, it works like a Data Area. All I am trying to do is open a web form and get a sequence number. I will store the value later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ... INTO` needs a row to run against, and you are not providing any, thus you have no result set.

There are two ways to do what you want.

Using `SELECT INTO` with `SYSDUMMY1`

```
select next value for @sop_seq
  into :seq
  from sysibm/sysdummy1;
```

Or, better, using `VALUES INTO` which does not need the reference to `SYSDUMMY1`

```
values next value for @sop_seq
  into :seq;
```

tldr;
`SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1` is a catalog file with a single record, and before `VALUES INTO` became available, was commonly used to retrieve calculated values into a result set when a single row is required, and there is no real table reference that applies (as in your situation here). This technique is still used, but I would advise toward using `VALUES INTO` instead as no artificial `FROM` clause is necessary.

Comment: When I use the second option you suggested I get the following error: SQL1105 Object @SOP_SEQ in *LIBL not found

Comment: @Tretiak apparently whatever library (schema) the sequence object is in is not in your library list.   Either add it to the *LIBL or qualify it in the statement `for mylib.@sopseq`

Comment: OK, thank you guys. This is exactly what I was looking for. I also discovered that Identity columns is another options that I can use in the future.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, I wanted to PM you but I see no option to do so. I was curious to know if you are using a PHP framework or core PHP?

Comment: I'm not currently using PHP, but if I were, I would use a framework for new work.